# Debug a site behind SSL

Tags: debugging, ssl

I'm in the process of putting my whole website behind SSL because something requires it right now. It's the first time I do that. I normally debug my (php/asp.net) website via Wireshark, and I really worry about the fact this will be totally obscure/encrypted once running in SSL.

Should I say goodbye to fast, simple debugging with a packet sniffer, or there are well-known practices to debug it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decrypt (some) SSL traffic with WireShark.  Since you own the domain, you own the private key the site will use.  Configure WireShark to use it to decrypt the traffic to/from your site.

http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL/

https://wirewatcher.wordpress.com/2010/07/20/decrypting-ssl-traffic-with-wireshark-and-ways-to-prevent-it/